# how to extract ngram from R when couldn't install RWeka

Tags: r, text, text-mining, tm

I intend to get ngram from this vector in R. Couldn't install RWeka/rJava no matter what I did, so I looked for an alternative which is ngram package. However, there is something wrong with this script and it doesn't work.

```
library(tm)
library(ngram)
text=c("A vector of n-grams","listed in decreasing blocks","it is a vector","it works a little differently","there are many vectors","another vector")
myCorpus=VCorpus(VectorSource(text))
bigram_tokenizer <- function(x) 
ngram_asweka(x, min = 2, max = 2)
bigram_tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus)
findFreqTerms(bigram_tdm, 3)
```

What is causing the character(0) error and how to deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: "vector" it is only twice... try to add an extra string `text <- c(text, "another vector")`

Comment: `character(0)` means that nothing has been found

Comment: thank you @EnriquePérezHerrero I added and the results return 'vector' now, but since I specified nmin=2, why isn't it returning a bigram like 'a vector'?

Answer (score 2):

Finding bigrams is easier with `ngram` package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ngram/vignettes/ngram-guide.pdf

```
library(ngram)

text <- c("A vector of n-grams",
       "listed in decreasing blocks",
       "it is a vector",
       "it works a little differently",
       "there are many vectors",
       "a vector")
bigrams <- ngram(text, n = 2)
phrase_table <- get.phrasetable(bigrams)

phrase_table

#                    ngrams freq       prop
#1            a vector     2 0.11764706
#2            a little     1 0.05882353
#3  little differently     1 0.05882353
#4            it works     1 0.05882353
#5           there are     1 0.05882353
#6   decreasing blocks     1 0.05882353
#7       in decreasing     1 0.05882353
#8           listed in     1 0.05882353
#9               it is     1 0.05882353
#10               is a     1 0.05882353
#11           A vector     1 0.05882353
#12         of n-grams     1 0.05882353
#13          vector of     1 0.05882353
#14            works a     1 0.05882353
#15           are many     1 0.05882353
#16       many vectors     1 0.05882353
```

Comment: thank you! most helpful. wondering if to make a tdm, how to pass this bigram as a control parameter, or should I turn it into bigram phrase_table first, then make a tdm out of it?